# Formatting of displayed section numbers

Tags: sectioning, numbering

I am using article class. There are no chapters in the document. I want the section numbers to read as 1.1, 1.2, .... and then  2.1, 2.2, ..., and then 3.1, 3.2, ...

I have tried the code below

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{1.\arabic{section}} % one block of sections
\section{ section one}
\section{second}
\section{third}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{2.\arabic{section}} % another block of sections
\section{First section}
\section{Second}

\end{document}
```

The code above gives 1.1, 1.2, 1.3 and then 2.4, 2.5. What I want is 1.1, 1.2, 1.3 and then 2.1, 2.2. Is there any way to do this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that what you want is to define a counter called, say, `block`, and "tie" the `section` counter (that's the counter that's stepped each time the `\section` macro is executed) to the `block` counter. By "tie", I mean that (a) the `section` counter is reset to 0 each time the `block` counter is stepped and (b) the `section` number is shown as being subordinated to the `block` number.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{block}
\counterwithin{section}{block} % tie 'section' counter to 'block' counter 

\begin{document}

\stepcounter{block} % one block of sections
\section{ section one}
\section{second}
\section{third}

\stepcounter{block} % another block of sections
\section{First section}
\section{Second}

\end{document}
```

---

That said, I'd also like to suggest that you start using `\subsection` commands instead of `\section` commands, as the `subsection` counter is tied to the `section` counter by default.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\stepcounter{section} % first block
\subsection{first}
\subsection{second}
\subsection{third}

\stepcounter{section} % another block
\subsection{First}
\subsection{Second}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Mico, your solution perfectly gives me what I wanted.